# wordpress 403 Permission Denied on pdf, doc (other than jpeg, png)

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, file-upload

I am facing some weird problem in my wordpress site. I can able to upload files (images, pdfs, docs) using media. But I can only see the images (jpeg and png) only. When I check the pdf path, it showing error

```
403 Permission Denied

You do not have permission for this request /wp-content/uploads/2015/04/cbse-application-form-3.pdf
```

I checked with .htaccess file too, deleted and regenerated with default settings.

File permission also checked. folders 755 and files in 644.

Previously it was working fine. Suddenly it happens. I disabled all plugins and also checked. No improvement.

Please kindly help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Please set the permission to 777 to upload folder and check it.

Comment: Changed that too. Not worked

Answer (score 0):

change 'recently_edited' row values in wp_options table to your hosts right path. It worked on me.

Answer (score -1):

This bug appears when the siteurl is different to the homeurl of your site, which you set in the wordpress backend.

edit: You may have some old paths. Check your db.

Comment: both smae only. In my case

Comment: Did you check the paths in your phpmyadmin db? There should be a wp-contents table.

Comment: I checked home and site url same only. And also, i dont have wp-contents table

Comment: And also, this working fine previously. Now suddenly some problem happens